# 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in Odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'm trying to show report based on user choice, this is code in file .py:

```
@api.multi
def render_html(self,data=None,context=None):

    if data['region_id']==True or data['location_id']==False or data['no_zero']==False:
        report=self.env['report']
        document=self._get_report_s_r(data)
        docss=self._get_report_s_r_detail(data)
        ctx=self._context.copy()
        object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
        data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
        return report.render('report.report_s', data)

    elif data['region_id']==False or data['location_id']==True or data['no_zero']==False:
        report=self.env['report']
        document=self._get_report_s_false(data)
        docss=self._get_report_s_false_detail(data)
        ctx=self._context.copy()
        object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
        data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
        return report.render('report.pos_report_sales', data)

    elif data['region_id']==False or data['location_id']==True or data['no_zero']==True:
        report=self.env['report']
        document=self._get_report_s(data)
        docss=self._get_report_s_detail(data)
        ctx=self._context.copy()
        object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
        data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
        return report.render('report.pos_report_s', data)

    else:
        _logger.error('Required document not set in Report!')
```

1. region_id = True, location_id = False, no_zero = False : Correct
2. region_id = False, location_id = True, no_zero = False : Error ('bool' object has no attribute '**getitem**')
3. region_id = False, location_id = True, no_zero = True : Wrong (Show that should be number 2)
4. region_id = True, location_id = True, no_zero = True : Wrong (Show that should be number 3)
5. If I change 'or' with 'and', all report is error (blank).

Hope someone helps me. Thankyou!

Comment: Can you show the log please, the line where the error occurred ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170820\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 387, in old_api
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170820\server\openerp\addons\report\models\report.py", line 93, in render_html
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170820\server\openerp\addons\report\models\report.py", line 117, in _get_report
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: You neet to locate the log line pointing to your code.and return default value in case the caller expect a result not None.

Comment: I think, I've found the solution. I order the True, if True is one then in top position, if True is two then below it, etc?

Comment: Good and think to add your solution bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I order the True and found the solution with this code:

```
@api.multi
def render_html(self,data=None,context=None):

if data['region_id']==True or (data['location_id']==False and data['no_zero']==False):
    report=self.env['report']
    document=self._get_report_s_r(data)
    docss=self._get_report_s_r_detail(data)
    ctx=self._context.copy()
    object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
    data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
    return report.render('report.report_s', data)

elif data['location_id']==True or (data['region_id']==False and data['no_zero']==False):
    report=self.env['report']
    document=self._get_report_s_false(data)
    docss=self._get_report_s_false_detail(data)
    ctx=self._context.copy()
    object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
    data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
    return report.render('report.pos_report_sales', data)

elif (data['location_id']==True and data['no_zero']==True) or data['region_id']==False:
    report=self.env['report']
    document=self._get_report_s(data)
    docss=self._get_report_s_detail(data)
    ctx=self._context.copy()
    object=self.env['report.wizard'].browse([ctx['active_id']])
    data={'o':object,'docs':document,'docss':docss}
    return report.render('report.pos_report_s', data)

else:
    _logger.error('Required document not set in Report!')
```

But, I'm not sure can work for all case.